# VBA - Refer to values in Object List

Tags: vba

I am not sure how to refer to the values in the tables, i.e. it is an object list. I want to set the values of one column in a table to be equal to another column in a table. I have many rows.

This is before the code:

[image]

This is an outcome after the code I wish to have:

[image]

Since it is table, I cannot use a simple code of a type:

```
   .Columns(3).Cells = .Columns(1).Cells.Value
```

Here, how I was trying to achieve it by referring to List Object but it does not work:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
   .ListColumns(3) = .ListColumns(1)
    ??????
End With
```

I will appreciate the help on how to properly refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    .ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Value = .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
End With
```

There is a good guide to tables [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)

Comment: Thank you very much